# devtools DESCRIPTION file

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am trying to create a package with devtools. I want to set a few options so that the DESCRIPTION file is auto-populated. I can't seem to get it right.

This is a problem that can be easily fixed manually, I think, but I want this to work in code. Worried the error will affect me later. Any suggestions on appropriate syntax? I have my functions in a folder called "R". I set my working directory to the parent folder for R. Then:

```
library(devtools)

install_github("devtools")

options(devtools.desc.author="First Last <first.last@example.com> [aut, cre]")

options(devtools.desc.license="GPL-3")

load_all()
```

This outputs this:

```
No DESCRIPTION found. Creating default:

Package: mypackage
Title: 
Description: 
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: First Last <first.last@example.com> [aut, cre]
Depends: R (>= 3.0.1)
License: GPL-3
LazyData: true
Loading mypackage
Invalid DESCRIPTION:
Malformed Authors@R field:
 <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: First Last
         ^

Required fields missing:
  Author Maintainer

See the information on DESCRIPTION files in section 'Creating R packages' of the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.
```

I am aware that in some way the Authors@R field can/is in some way replacing the Maintainer field, but wondering how to get this to stop throwing errors, and what they mean.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately you need:

```
options(devtools.desc.author="'First Last <first.last@example.com> [aut, cre]'")
```

because the contents of `Authors@R` must be a valid R expression.

Or using the `person` function from the `utils` package:

```
authors_at_r <- paste0(
  "'", 
  person(
    "First", 
    "Last", 
    email = "first.last@example.com", 
    role  = c("aut", "cre")), 
  "'"
)
options(devtools.desc.author=authors)
```

Comment: With the addition of a single quote to close the R expression, this works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @forlooper -- There, I added the missing single quote.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien -- Thank you, didn't realize you could edit others responses

Comment: Been looking for that, too. I think it would be good to add it to the `?devtools` page, close to where you refer to `as.person`. It's really one of those things that are hard to google and only learned by example if you do not know them already.

Comment: what if there are multiple authors that you want to add? Just `authors_at_r <- paste0("'", aut1, "'","'", aut2, "'")`?

Comment: or better to put the authors together using something like this: `c.aut <- function(...){
 sapply(list(...), function(x)paste0("'",x,"'"))
}`